# How to get weekly datetime ranges between two datetimes and return a dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have the following date range:

```
first_date = '2021-01-01 00:00:00'
end_date = '2021-12-31 23:59:59'
```

The output I am trying to achieve is a dataframe of weekly dates so that the data can be fetched for a month in its entirety

Df

```
|Start_Date|End_Date|
----------------------
| 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | 2021-01-08 23:59:59 |
| 2021-01-09 00:00:00 | 2021-01-15 23:59:59 |
| 2021-01-16 00:00:00 | 2021-01-22 23:59:59 |
| 2021-01-23 00:00:00 | 2021-01-29 23:59:59 |
| 2021-01-30 00:00:00 | 2021-01-31 23:59:59 |
| 2021-02-01 00:00:00 | 2021-02-08 23:59:59 |
| 2021-02-09 00:00:00 | 2021-02-15 23:59:59 |
.
.
.
| 2021-12-01 00:00:00 | 2021-12-08 23:59:59 |
| 2021-12-09 00:00:00 | 2021-12-15 23:59:59 |
| 2021-12-16 00:00:00 | 2021-12-22 23:59:59 | 
| 2021-12-23 00:00:00 | 2021-12-29 23:59:59 |
| 2021-12-30 00:00:00 | 2021-12-31 23:59:59 |
```

How do I define a generator function get_date_intervals(st_dt, end_dt, intv) to get the above output

So far, this is what I can think of:

```py
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from datetime import date 
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

monthStart = pd.date_range(start=fd,end=ed, freq='MS').strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

monthEnd = pd.date_range(start=fd,end=ed, freq='M').strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

l = [(s,e) for s,e in zip(monthStart, monthEnd)]

df = pd.DataFrame(l, columns=["Start_Date", "End_Date"])

df['Start_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start_Date'])

df['End_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End_Date'])

df_out = pd.DataFrame()

week = 7

# Iterate over dataframe rows

 for index, row in df.iterrows():

    date_st = row["Start_Date"]

    date_end = row["End_Date"]

    # Get the weeks for the row
    while date_st < date_end:

        if (date_end-date_st).days >= 7:

            date_next = date_st + datetime.timedelta(week)

            df_out = df_out.append([[date_st, date_next]])

            date_st = date_next + datetime.timedelta(0)

        else:

            date_next = date_st + datetime.timedelta((date_end-date_st).days)

            df_out = df_out.append([[date_st, date_next]])

            date_st = date_next + datetime.timedelta(0)
        

# Remove extra index and assign columns as original dataframe
df_out = df_out.reset_index(drop=True)

df_out.columns = df.columns



if len(df_out)%2==0:

    for i in range(0, len(df_out)):

        if i%2 != 0:

            df_out['End_date_new'][i] = df_out['End_Date'][i].strftime("%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59")

        else:

            df_out['End_date_new'][i] =  df_out['End_Date'][i].strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
else:

    for i in range(0, len(df_out)):

        if i%2 == 0:

            df_out['End_date_new'][i] = df_out['End_Date'][i].strftime("%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59")

        else:

            df_out['End_date_new'][i] =  df_out['End_Date'][i].strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

I am close but cannot get my head wrap around getting the desired interval.

Comment: `pd.date_range(start=fd, end=ed, freq='7d')`?

Comment: I tried but it doesn't give me the interval I am looking for

Comment: could you let me know how is it different from what you are looking for with some examples?

Comment: Hey Emma, thanks for helping me out, I solved it, using date_st = date_next + datetime.timedelta(days=1)